# converting double values for making a Point type

Tags: c#, double, point

I want to draw a curve (a diode curve) in a picturebox using imagefrom bitmap. I have a problem now and it is my point data are saved as Double and it is really important to keep the precesion.

for example a point in the plot I have is like this:

> Voltage: -0.175       Current: -9.930625E-06

Yes, it is a Double! now how can I have a point to do for example:

```
        Point[] ptarray = new Point[3];
        ptarray[0] = new Point(250, 250);
```

Is there an alternative to Point[] that accepts double values? I have a 500x500 picture box. is there a way to convert those values to valid points that can still save precesion? I am wotking with micro Ampers (10^-6) and Voltages!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, if `float` is enough precision, then you can use the [`PointF` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.aspx):

```
var point = new PointF(3.5f, 7.9f);
```

If you really need to, you can define your own `PointD` struct:

```
public struct PointD {
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public PointD(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public Point ToPoint() {
        return new Point((int)X, (int)Y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
      return obj is PointD && this == (PointD)obj;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
      return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode();
    }
    public static bool operator ==(PointD a, PointD b) {
      return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(PointD a, PointD b) {
      return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

Equality code originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502451/c-what-needs-to-be-overriden-in-a-struct-to-ensure-equality-operates-properly/1502479#1502479).

The `ToPoint()` method lets you convert it to a `Point` object, though of course the precision will be truncated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5221407/380384 for the proper `GetHashCode()` for structures.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for storing these values there's always [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
Tuple<double, double>[] Points = new Tuple<double, double>[50];
Points[0] = Tuple.Create<double, double>(5.33, 12.45);
```

Comment: tuples don't add any context and is way to general and makes the code hard to read. I'd say use them as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `System.Drawing.Point` struct uses `int` values, and the `System.Drawing.PointF` struct uses `float` values, there is also the `System.Windows.Point` struct, which uses `double` values. So this is probably your best choice, if `float` does not provide enough precision for your needs.

However, since the name of the struct conflicts with that of the `int`-based one, it can be unwieldy to use in a file that already has a `using System.Drawing` directive in it:

```
using System.Drawing;
...
System.Windows.Point coords = new System.Windows.Point(1.5, 3.9);
```

Fortunately, you can get around this by using an alias:

```
using System.Drawing;
using PointD = System.Windows.Point;
...
PointD coords = new PointD(1.5, 3.9);
```