# Substitute the GetHashCode() Method of System.Drawing.Point

Tags: c#, performance, gdi+, gethashcode

`System.Drawing.Point` has a really, really bad `GetHashCode` method if you intend to use it to describes 'pixels' in a Image/Bitmap: [it is just XOR between the X and Y coordinates.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Point.cs,a041be61667d4c9a)

So for a image with, say, 2000x2000 size, it has an absurd number of colisions, since only the numbers in the diagonal are going to have a decent hash.

It's quite easy to create a decent `GetHashCode` method using unchecked multiplication, as some people already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221396/what-is-an-appropriate-gethashcode-algorithm-for-a-2d-point-struct-avoiding).

But what can I do to use this improved `GetHashCode` method in a `HashSet`?
I know I could create my own class/struct `MyPoint` and implement it using this improved methods, but then I'd break all other pieces of code in my project that use a `System.Drawing.Point`.

Is it possible to "overwrite" the method from `System.Drawing.Point` using some sort of extension method or the like? Or to "tell" the `HashSet` to use another function instead of the `GetHashCode`?

Currently I'm using a `SortedSet<System.Drawing.Point>` with a custom `IComparer<Point>` to store my points. When I want to know if the set contains a Point I call `BinarySearch`. It's faster than a `HashSet<System.Drawing.Point>.Contains` method in a set with 10000 colisions, but it's no as fast as `HashSet` with a good hash could be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own class that implements [`IEqualityComparer<Point>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then give that class to the [`HashSet` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
public class MyPointEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return p1 == p2; // defer to Point's existing operator==
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point obj)
    {
        return /* your favorite hashcode function here */;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create hashset with custom hashcode algorithm
        HashSet<Point> myHashSet = new HashSet<Point>(new MyPointEqualityComparer());

        // Same thing also works for dictionary
        Dictionary<Point, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<Point, string>(new MyPointEqualityComparer());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! I didn't notice that a IEqualityComparer had a GetHashCode() method! Perfect answer!