# Comparing object used as Key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, comparison, equals, contains

my class:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
}
```

and main example:

```
Dictionary<myClass, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<myClass, List<string>>();
myClass first = new myClass();
first.A = 2;
first.B = 3;

myClass second = new myClass();
second.A = 2;
second.B = 3;
second.C = 5;
second.D = 6;

dict.Add(first, new List<string>());

if (dict.ContainsKey(second))
{
    //
    //should come here and update List<string> for first (and only in this example) key 
    //
}
else
{
    //
    //if myFirst object has difference vlues of A or B properties
    //
    dict.Add(second, new List<string>());
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: do you want first to be considered as equal to second only on A and B values equality?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you **always** want the dictionary only to compare on A and B, you have two options. Either [use the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072) that implements `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` and put your comparison logic there, or have your class implement <s>[`IEquateable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187)</s> *GetHashCode and Equals* so the default comparer will give you the results you are looking for.

If you only want to compare on A and B in your one situation you will need to use the .Keys property and the Linq extension method [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118) that allows you to pass in a `IEqualityComparer<T>`. However, when doing it this way you loose the speed benefits of using a Dictionary, so use it sparingly.

```
public class MyClassSpecialComparer : IEqualityComparer<myClass>
{
    public bool Equals (myClass x, myClass y)
    { 
        return x.A == y.A && x.B == y.B 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(myClass x)
    {
       return x.A.GetHashCode() + x.B.GetHashCode();
    }


}


 //Special case for when you only want it to compare this one time
 //NOTE: This will be much slower than a normal lookup.
    var myClassSpecialComparer = new MyClassSpecialComparer();
    Dictionary<myClass, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<myClass, List<string>>();
    //(Snip)
    if (dict.Keys.Contains(second, myClassSpecialComparer ))
    {
        //
        //should come here and update List<string> for first (and only in this example) key 
        //
    }

 //If you want it to always compare
    Dictionary<myClass, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<myClass, List<string>>(new MyClassSpecialComparer());
```

Answer (score 13):

By default, comparison puts objects into buckets based on their hash code.  A detailed comparison is then performed (by calling `Equals`) if two hash codes are the same.  If your class neither provides `GetHashCode` or implements equality, the default `object.GetHashCode` will be used--in which case nothing specific to your class will be used for value comparison semantics.  Only the same reference will be found.  If you don't want this, implement `GetHashCode` and implement equality.

For example:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(myClass other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return other.A == A && other.B == B && other.C == C && other.D == D;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (myClass)) return false;
        return Equals((myClass) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int result = A;
            result = (result*397) ^ B;
            result = (result*397) ^ C;
            result = (result*397) ^ D;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderEfimov That makes it so the code is order dependent if you just XORed all of the items `A = 1, B = 2` would generate the same hash `3` has `A = 2, B = 1`. However if you multiply the second item by 397 it gives you  `A = 1, B = 2` generates` 795`, but `A = 2, B = 1` generates `399`. This gives you a better hash distribution (one note, you should add not xor and initialize the first number with another prime)

Comment: See [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892618/create-a-hashcode-of-two-numbers) for more of a explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Override in your myClass:

- GetHashCode method
- Equals method

To implement GetHashCode method you can just XOR GetHashCodes from your integer properties.

Optionally override ToString method and implement IEquatable interface