# How to override the default comparer for dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

If I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<SomeClass, int> MyDict { get; set; } = ...
```

how can I override the compare method that gets called when it is evaluating a key?

As in - I want to be in control of which object gets picked when I write

```
MyDict[SomeClassInstance]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing object used as Key in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562996/comparing-object-used-as-key-in-dictionary). [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563134/1797425) this answer as it is what you would need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement an [`IEqualityComparer<TKey>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) and pass an instance of this to the dictionary's [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__):

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public bool Equals(object o1, object o2)
    {
        // implement your way of equality 
    }
    public int GetHashCode(object o)
    {
        // implement a hash method that returns equal hashes for equal
        // objects and well distributed hashes for not-equal objects
    }
}

Dictionary<object, int> myDict = new Dictionary<object, int>(new MyComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to [use the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__) that allows you to pass in an instance of `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`, which would then be used for your key comparisons. I don't believe you can change this after instantiation.

Comment: you mean derive from ``IEqualityComparer<TKey>``? sounds weird to me to keep an instance of it

Comment: Yes, you would implement `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` as some class, then pass an instance of that class to the constructor.

Comment: yeah, that's what the other person said aswell, thanks I'll use that