# Create Unique Hashcode for the permutation of two Order Ids

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, dictionary, gethashcode

I have a collection which is a permutation of two unique orders, where OrderId is unique. Thus it contains the `Order1 (Id = 1)` and `Order2 (Id = 2)` as both `12` and `21`. Now while processing a routing algorithm, few conditions are checked and while a combination is included in the final result, then its reverse has to be ignored and needn't be considered for processing. Now since the Id is an integer, I have created a following logic:

```
 private static int GetPairKey(int firstOrderId, int secondOrderId)
        {
            var orderCombinationType = (firstOrderId < secondOrderId)
                ? new {max = secondOrderId, min = firstOrderId}
                : new { max = firstOrderId, min = secondOrderId };

            return (orderCombinationType.min.GetHashCode() ^ orderCombinationType.max.GetHashCode());
        }
```

In the logic, I create a `Dictionary<int,int>`, where key is created using the method `GetPairKey` shown above, where I ensure that out of given combination they are arranged correctly, so that I get the same Hashcode, which can be inserted and checked for an entry in a Dictionary, while its value is dummy and its ignored.

However above logic seems to have a flaw and it doesn't work as expected for all the logic processing, what am I doing wrong in this case, shall I try something different to create a `Hashcode`. Is something like following code a better choice, please suggest

`Tuple.Create(minOrderId,maxOrderId).GetHashCode`, following is relevant code usage:

```
  foreach (var pair in localSavingPairs)
            {
                    var firstOrder = pair.FirstOrder;
                    var secondOrder = pair.SecondOrder;

                   if (processedOrderDictionary.ContainsKey(GetPairKey(firstOrder.Id, secondOrder.Id))) continue;
```

Adding to the Dictionary, is the following code:

`processedOrderDictionary.Add(GetPairKey(firstOrder.Id, secondOrder.Id), 0);` here the value 0 is dummy and is not used

Comment: If the hash code is an integer, and the two ids are integers, you can't create perfectly unique hashes, due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). You have 2^32 possible hashes, and 2^63 tuples you have to assign them to.

Comment: Can you show the code that uses this with a dictionary? From what you describe it might be far from optimal, but it should still work.

Comment: Do I have any option to make this work, to get the unique for the combination of Ids

Comment: Since dictionaries handle collisions, there's no reason why you should need unique IDs. (Keeping collisions low would certainly be beneficial though).

Comment: @JonHanna updated the usage

Comment: Oh. I see. yeah, don't do that. Answer to follow.

Comment: Are you using hashcodes with the assumption that you can create unique identifiers for a pair of values? That's not going to work out well for you because, fundamentally, hashcodes are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @spender there is such a thing as "perfect hashing" where they do, so in terms of the wider study of hash-codes, what you say is not correct, though it certainly is correct in terms of what is being attempted here.

Comment: @JonHanna Sure, but a perfect hash that covers two ints but fits into an int  is impossible.

Comment: @spender a perfect hash also isn't possible without prior knowledge of the range of values, so again, not applicable here.

Comment: @JonHanna A "perfect hash" *isn't a hash*. That's a paradoxical concept. The whole point of a hash is something that helps sort data into reasonably distinct buckets for any particular data set. Any data set with a possible range of values greater than the hash set's possible range of values is susceptible to collisions, any data set smaller than the hash set isn't really being hashed (or, more correctly, doesn't even need hashing).

Comment: @ErikE they need hashing in precisely the sort of cases perfect hashes are used for; you can't index into an array or jump-table with `"orange"` or into one with 10 elements with both `12` and `1234212`.

Comment: @jon I guess I see your point, however I still maintain that "perfect hash" is by itself nonsense. A custom hash over a defined dataset that yields no collisions (because the hash space is larger than the defined set) is possible, but far from "perfect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a value that can uniquely represent every possible value.

That is different to a hash-code.

You could uniquely represent each value with a `long` or with a class or struct that contains all of the appropriate values. Since after a certain total size using `long` won't work any more, let's look at the other approach, which is more flexible and more extensible:

```
public class KeyPair : IEquatable<KeyPair>
{
  public int Min { get; private set; }
  public int Max { get; private set; }

  public KeyPair(int first, int second)
  {
    if (first < second)
    {
      Min = first;
      Max = second;
    }
    else
    {
      Min = second;
      Max = first;
    }
  }

  public bool Equals(KeyPair other)
  {
    return other != null && other.Min == Min && other.Max == Max;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object other)
  {
    return Equals(other as KeyPair);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return unchecked(Max * 31 + Min);
  }
}
```

Now, the `GetHashCode()` here will not be unique, but the `KeyPair` itself will be. Ideally the hashcodes will be very different to each other to better distribute these objects, but doing much better than the above depends on information about the actual values that will be seen in practice.

The dictionary will use that to find the item, but it will also use `Equals` to pick between those where the hash code is the same.

(You can experiment with this by having a version for which `GetHashCode()` always just returns `0`. It will have very poor performance because collisions hurt performance and this will always collide, but it will still work).

Comment: You might want to consider enclosing the hashcode calculation with `unchecked`

Comment: This is the right answer. Just addressing how to compute a hashcode isn't going to solve the OP's issue. Your answer could be improved by showing him that the `KeyPair` itself is used as the key of the dictionary `Add` method.

Comment: @ErikE And, amusingly enough, the dictionary itself will internally compute a hash-code for the pair in a way that would have been a good answer for the OP.

Comment: @btilly I think that's incorrect. Without making the `KeyPair` object implement `IEquatable`, it will use reference equality for object keys, so  a `KeyPair` not implementing `IEquatable` would NOT throw in this scenario: `var dict = new Dictionary<KeyPair, string>(); dict.Add(new KeyPair(1, 2), "first"); dict.Add(new KeyPair(2, 1), "second");` whereas this code DOES throw using this answer's `KeyPair : IEquatable<KeyPair>`.

Comment: If it was a struct it would have, but poorly. If it was an anonymous class it would do a better job.

Comment: @JonHanna thanks for the great explanation and a very nice option to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

First, `42.GetHashCode()` returns 42. Second, `1 ^ 2` is identical to `2 ^ 1`, so there's really no point in sorting numbers. Third, your "hash" function is very weak and produces a lot of collisions, which is why you're observing the flaws.

There are two options I can think of right now:

- Use a slightly "stronger" [hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/892618/60188)
- Replace your `Dictionary<int, int>` key with `Dictionary<string, int>` with keys being your two sorted numbers separated by whatever character you prever -- e.g. `56-6472`

Comment: My understanding remains a Dictionary where I can provide a unique string, as suggested, using any acceptable special character like '-' or '%', would always generate a unique key for a given combination or do I still have a scope of dealing with the situation where there could be collision

Answer (score 2):

Given that XOR is commutative (so `(a ^ b)` will always be the same as `(b ^ a)`) it seems to me that your ordering is misguided... I'd just

```
(new {firstOrderId, secondOrderId}).GetHashCode()
```

.Net will fix you up a good well-distributed hashing implementation for anonymous types.

Comment: Thanks let me try, but still I would need to sort the Ids correct, that is how I would get a unique Id for a given combination

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the ids"? You're not guarantee to get a unique hash code, period.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Ah... now we move on to a different issue altogether. Using a hashcode as a measure of uniqueness is a terrible idea. There is no guarantee that it will produce a unique id. That is not what hashcodes are for. If you want a guaranteed unique value, then I'd consider a `long` with `(value1<<32) + value2`

Comment: I think you're missing what the OP is asking for. He wants to make sure that the set `{ 1, 2 }` produces the same hashcode as `{ 2, 1 }`. I do think he is a little unclear on hash collisions and needs help there, but I think the answer is to introduce him to custom IEqualityComparers. His method of ensuring the same hashcode is produced is ordering the two numbers so `{ 2, 1 }` is resolved to `{ 1, 2 }` before hashing. Thus, your answer seems to miss the mark as it completely ignores this aspect.