# TLE in backpack problem using memoization

Tags: c++, algorithm, memoization

**Problem Statement:**
Given n items with size Ai, an integer m denotes the size of a backpack. How full you can fill this backpack?

Example
Example 1:
    Input:  [3,4,8,5], backpack size=10
    Output:  9

Example 2:
    Input:  [2,3,5,7], backpack size=12
    Output:  12

I have to write solution using memoization , I know bottom up dp will be quite fast ,But can you help me with other optimisation that i can add in this solution.

```
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<string,int>m1;
    int solve(int m,vector<int>&a,int i){
        if(i<0)return 0;

        string s = to_string(m)+" "+to_string(i);
        if(m1.count(s))return m1[s];
        int val=0;
        if(m-a[i]>=0)val = a[i] + solve(m-a[i],a,i-1);
        return m1[s]=max(val,solve(m,a,i-1));

    }
    int backPack(int m, vector<int> &a) {
        // write your code here
       return solve(m,a,int(a.size()-1));
    }
};
```

Comment: instead of map use an array

Comment: All that string building takes more time than you think. Use `std::pair<int,int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a hash of two integers `m` and `i` by following an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892618/create-a-hashcode-of-two-numbers)
and use that as key in your map. You should see an improvement in runtime although bottom up solution is superior.
In your code, the `to_string` takes time and also it takes more time to look up for the string than you think as mentioned in the comments.