# How to guarantee unique int (or bigint) key for postgres materialzied view

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, uuid, materialized-views

I am wondering if I can achieve this using a postgres view (or materialized view) rather than a table.

Requirement:
I need a unique ID on my view that must always belong to the same row. My first thought was a composite key - there are two integer fields in my view that when combined would be unique. However of course (52, 6) will look the same as (5, 26) when combined.

As per [Is there a simple way to create a unique integer key from a two-integer composite key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745048/is-there-a-simple-way-to-create-a-unique-integer-key-from-a-two-integer-composit) it looks like a lot of complicated maths can be done to create a unique composite bigint value for a view, however I feel like this might be a bit hard to maintain.

I'm wondering if there's anything a materialized view might offer to ensure an ID is always unique and not changing, even once the view is refreshed.

I've tried `Row_number() over` but that is ruled out as, although it is unique, it changes each time.

I'm currently considering just using a table to get around this issue if there is nothing simple that achieves this.

Comment: The request is not clear to me. Why do you need a unique id in a view ? As far as I can remember, the only case where it is required is for a materialized view to be refreshed concurrently. Starting from two integers int1 and int2, it is simple to create one bigint which may be a unique id if the binome (int1, int2) is unique : (int1 * 2^32 + int2) :: bigint. This bigint is different for both binomes (52,6) and (5,26). Hope that will help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment - we need a unique id for a 3rd party piece of code that is really designed to be used with a table rather than a view. The id is used as a reference so must not change for that row ever.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a table with the two columns int1 and int2, then the `id = (int1 * 2^32 + int2) :: bigint` will not change until int1 and/or int2 are updated in the table. Then, this id can be stored in the table as a new column of type bigint, or you can create an index on that table which will store this id while being used when querying that table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigint_id(int1 integer, int2 integer)
RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
SELECT (int1 * 2^32 + int2) :: bigint ;
$$ ;

CREATE INDEX bigint_id ON your_table USING btree (bigint_id(int1, int2)) ;
```

The following query will use the bigint_id index :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE bigint_id(int1, int2) = nnnn
```