# Is the below is correct equals and hashCode implementation in Java?

Tags: java, hashcode

When an object's value is equal i need to return it is true.

example

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
return new HashCodeBuilder().append(value).toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
if (obj instanceof NumberValTO) {
  final NumberValTO other = (NumberVal) obj;
  return new EqualsBuilder().append(value, other.getValue()).isEquals();
}
return false;
}
```

Is the above is fine or wrong?

I saw in few applications where hashcode is being multiple with each and every field of the table and not sure whether it is a correct approach.

Assume an entity has 4 columns
Assume an entity has 2 columns

1. Which is the best approach to generate the same?
2. Also, do we need to implement hashcode() and equals() for a hibernate entity class?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what `HashCodeBuilder` & `EqualsBuilder` do. There might be multiplication (which is not required for correctness - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier)) inside.

Comment: Your `equals` method should also compare against null and compare against self (`this`). For eg see this [`link`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html)

Comment: Comparing to `this` is a good idea although it is just a performance optimization. `null` check is already included since `null instanceof Anything` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Do you see any problem in the above hashcode or equals ?? Why we need to write our own logic instead of using the above ??

Comment: @Vino `instanceof` returns false for null, and comparing to `this` is purely a performance optimisation. The method is fine.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers..Everyone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's fine, assuming those are the Apache Commons helper classes you're using. @Vino is correct to point out that  adding `if (obj == this) return true;` to the start of your `equals` method can be a worthwhile optimisation, but your methods look correct as is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

Your example is fine as it provides a fair implementation of equals and hashcode methods. I am using this way in my project.

To answer you 1 question You can read through http://www.ideyatech.com/2011/04/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/

To answer you 2 question follow link : [Hibernate: When is it necessary to implement equals() and hashCode(), and if so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089266/hibernate-when-is-it-necessary-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-and-if-so)

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals` and `hashCode` methods are both using the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from Apache's [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) correctly, though you should add a reference check - `if (obj == this) return true` - to the `equals` method.

An argument I've recently been given against using [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) was that it was less performant, so I tested it.

I created a `HashMap`, added 10K entries and then compared the look-up times for the same key object, once using a traditional `equals` and `hashCode`, then again with the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html).  The idea is that getting the values by their key will hammer the both the `equals` and `hashCode` methods and give a good comparison of their performance.

While the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) implementations where slower, the difference was in the region of 60ns with an average look-up time of about 320ns for the [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) implementation  and 260ns for the traditional approach (I've shown the code I used below).

IMHO this performance penalty should only be a concern where the `equals` and `hashCode` are called repeatedly over a large set of objects and even then, only where the small performance gain is worth sacrificing that clarity of you code.

Anyway, here's the class I used to test the performance difference:

```
public class Example
{
  private Type operationType;
  private long identity;
  private String name;
  private BigDecimal value;

  public Example(Type operationType, long identity, String name, BigDecimal value)
  {
    this.operationType = operationType;
    this.identity = identity;
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Example(Example example)
  {
    this.operationType = example.operationType;
    this.identity = example.identity;
    this.name = example.name;
    this.value = example.value;
  }

  public long getIdentity()
  {
    return identity;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public BigDecimal getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (Type.TRADITIONAL.equals(operationType))
    {
      if (this == obj)
      {
        return true;
      }
      if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
      {
        return false;
      }

      Example example = (Example)obj;
      return getIdentity() == example.getIdentity()
        && ((getName() == null && example.getName() == null) || getName().equals(example.getName ()))
        && ((getValue() == null && example.getValue() == null) || getValue().equals(example.getValue()));
    }
    else
    {
      return this == obj || obj instanceof Example &&
        new EqualsBuilder()
          .append(getIdentity(), ((Example)obj).getIdentity())
          .append(getName(), ((Example)obj).getName())
          .append(getValue(), ((Example)obj).getValue())
          .isEquals();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    if (Type.TRADITIONAL.equals(operationType))
    {
      int result = (int)(getIdentity() ^ (getIdentity() >>> 32));
      result = 31 * result + (getName() != null ? getName().hashCode() : 0);
      result = 31 * result + (getValue() != null ? getValue().hashCode() : 0);
      return result;
    }
    else
    {
      return new HashCodeBuilder().append(getIdentity()).append(getName()).append(getValue()).toHashCode();
    }
  }

  public static enum Type
  {
    TRADITIONAL,
    COMMONS
  }
}
```

And here's the test:

```
public class ExampleTest
{
  @Test
  public void testMapLookupWithTraditional() throws Exception
  {
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      total += testMapLookup(Example.Type.TRADITIONAL);
    }

    System.out.println("Overall Average: " + (total / 10));
  }

  @Test
  public void testMapLookupWithCommons() throws Exception
  {
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      total += testMapLookup(Example.Type.COMMONS);
    }

    System.out.println("Overall Average: " + (total / 10));
  }

  private double testMapLookup(Example.Type operationType) throws Exception
  {
    Map<Example, String> examples = new HashMap<Example, String>();

    while (examples.size() < 10000)
    {
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

      Example example = new Example(
        operationType,
        now,
        "EXAMPLE_" + now,
        new BigDecimal(now)
      );

      examples.put(example, example.getName());
      Thread.sleep(1);
    }

    int count = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double max = 0;
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Example example : examples.keySet())
    {
      Example copiedExample = new Example(example);

      long start = System.nanoTime();

      examples.get(copiedExample);

      long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;

      average = ((average * count++) + duration) / count;

      if (max < duration) max = duration;
      if (min > duration) min = duration;
    }

    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    System.out.println("Min: " + min);

    return average;
  }
}
```