# How to produce a unique number from combination of 2 numbers (in any order) in PHP?

Tags: php

How to produce a unique number from combination of 2 numbers in PHP ? For example, combination of these two numbers; 68 and 73, produce X ( X is a unique number). It does not matter how the order of the combination numbers, it should still produce same unique number. E.g: (68,73)=X or (73,68)=X
or combination of (1,2)=Y or (2,1)=Y , Y is a different number (because it's unique) from X.

Let me know if you need more information.

I think [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226317/generate-a-unique-value-for-a-combination-of-two-numbers) is similar to my problem but it is written in C#.

I converted this code to PHP :

```
function getUnique($x, $y){
  if($x>$y){
    return $y | $x << 32;
  }  else{
    return $x | $y << 32;
  }
}

$list = array();
for($i=0 ; $i<100 ;$i++){
  $x = rand(1,10); // I just put any random numbers from 1 to 10 so that I can read it easily.
  $y = rand(1,10);
  $unique = getUnique($x, $y);
  $list[$i] = '('.$x.','.$y.')='.$unique;
 }

//Find out the results
foreach($list as $ans){
   echo $ans.'<br>';
}
```

But, it does not produce unique numbers. Example from this results:

(2,9)=11

(10,1)=11

(2,9) should produce different number from (10,1).

Comment: Is there a maximum for the input numbers (for example 100)?  Such that you would never get (37,205).  If not, no.  If yes, then absolutely.

Comment: What do you mean by a unique number?

Comment: Are the numbers always integers, as in your examples?

Comment: are you looking for the value of X and Y. like 12+24= **36** and any combination of numbers that sum **36** your question is confusing.

Comment: @jedwards :There is no maximum input number.

Comment: Then no, it is not possible.  It would be possible if you specified a maximum input, otherwise unfortunately no.

Comment: This question seems legit. What's the reason to close? Anyway I have added a new answer in the same SO thread you posted which addresses your concern. Or see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871379/661933

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not in general (though there may be if you specify some restrictions).

Assuming *n*-bit types, there are 2<sup>*n*</sup> possible values.  But there are 2<sup>*2n*</sup> possible pairs of values.  Obviously there's not a unique mapping from a pair to a value.

Of course, if you're prepared to have an output type that's wider than your input type, then this is trivial.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.  In fact there is a way to produce what he is looking for if there is a maximum input.

Comment: @jedwards: So what do you interpret the question to mean?

Comment: Write a function that, given a set of numbers `(a,b)` produce a number `x` such that: `(b,a)` also produces `x` and no other `(a',b')` pair produces `x`.

Comment: @jedwards: Yes, that was my understanding too.

Comment: If the maximum input was 9, then sorting the numbers and concatenating them would do exactly what he wants.  (2,4) = 24 = (4,2).  No other acceptable `(a,b)` pair would result in 24.

Comment: +1 Oli is right you can't map 2 numbers to 1 unique number with a domain of -inf to inf

Comment: @jedwards: Yes, **if** there's such a restriction, then I agree.  Given no restriction, then there is no solution (which is what my answer says).

Comment: Which is what your answer says now, I agree, however originally you didn't have such a qualification.  Hence my comment.  Downvote revoked.

Comment: An edit or comment would have done instead of -1.

Comment: The answer was originally an unhelpful "No." followed by some justification.  When in fact, the answer is more complex as I indicated in my comment to the original question.

Comment: @jedwards: My answer was "no..." because the OP has currently specified no constraints.