# Combine two integers to create a unique number

Tags: c#, string, math, integer

Good Morning,

I was looking for a way to combine two integers to create a unique number, I have two tables that I need to combine into a third table with unique numbers,

These are my tables:

```
Table A 
SchoolID    ClassId
107 56644231
107 56644532
107 320110212

Table B 
SchoolID    ClassId
108 566442310
108 56644532
108 50110212
```

I need to export these fields to a third table combining class ID and school ID into one single field called classID. I need to be able to combine these numbers together and then be able to uncombine them to get schoolid and classid separate for update purposes. I was thinking of concatenating the strings `'schoolid + '00' + 'classid'` since I know that schoolid will always be a 3 digit number but I am looking for some other way perhaps mathematical where I don't have to use string casts.

Is there a mathematical way to do this? Or is casting to string the best way to do this?

I am using C# to code the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Be careful that you do not create a new number greater than the max capacity of the storage type.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Similar to Magnus Hoff, but I would recommend using a binary friendly approach instead of a base 10 approach.

```
combinedid = (classid << 8) + schoolid;
```

And then, later:

```
classid = combinedid >> 8;
schoolid = combinedid & 0xFF;
```

I think this is a little more straight forward from a programming standpoint (making it clear that your school ID is 1 byte (0-255), the class ID is 3 bytes).

You could also easily do this with a bigint (Long / Int64), making two int32's a single int64 safely:

```
combinedid = ((long)classid << 32) + schoolid;
```

Comment: I like your answer a lot. Thanks.

Comment: if classid is an int32 as mentioned, the code is not correct
    (classid << 32) will equal classid as it wraps around. correct would be:
    UInt64 combined = classid;
    combined <<= 32; // now it does not wrap around
    combined += schoolid;

Comment: @thomas - Technically you're right. I've updated it to cast classid to long before the bit shift.

Comment: This is a really cool approach, but what about ambiguous situations like `(0 << 8) + 256` and `(1 << 8) + 0`? (Both `256`) Or, a less-contrived example: `(100 << 8) + 100` and `(99 << 8) + 356` (Both 25700). Doesn't this lead to an ambiguous encoding?

Comment: @rinogo "making it clear that your school ID is 1 byte (0-255), the class ID is 3 bytes"

Comment: @userx: The only property that OP mentioned was "schoolid will always be a 3 digit number", so I'm not sure this is technically answering the question. However, with your modified prerequisites, this approach works!

Answer (score 9):

```
combinedid = classid*1000 + schoolid
```

And then, later:

```
classid = combinedid / 1000 // Integer division
schoolid = combinedid % 1000
```

Comment: Like @JTA commented on the question, be careful there's no overflow.

Answer (score 6):

I would combine the ID like this:

```
ID = ClassID * 1000 + SchoolID
```

You can then get the `SchoolID` like this:

```
SchoolID = ID % 1000
```

and you can get the `ClassID` like this:

```
ClassID = ID / 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ((a + b)(a + b + 1) * 0.5) + b
Reference
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Answer (score 2):

You indicate that you are working with a table. This leads me to believe that you are working within a database.

So I have to ask, why not store them in separate columns and make them simple foreign keys? Why create the ambiguity of trying to concatenate or transform the numbers with a math equation?

If you use another table, you can use an auto increment field and the combination of the three fields (in the order you designate) will give you a unique ID.

```
|-------------------
| My_combine_table
|-------------------
| id   | auto_inc 
|-------------------
| SchoolID | ...
| SchoolID2 | ...
```

Comment: I am exporting to a third party system which I have no control of. The local system is setup so that each school gets its own database, so I cannot control the classid's to be unique across all databases. The third party system does not have a place for schoolId, only ClassID

Answer (score 2):

If SchoolID is always a 3 digit number multiply ClassId by 1000 then add SchoolID.

Your number might "overflow" though., and given the ones you have if they are 32-bit they will.

Comment: The system expect 32 bit integers so this may be a big problem. I hadn't thought of this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way) has detailed various other mathematical approaches, some are just better. But for your case I suspect if those are hardly good ideas. I would say you should save the two ids in a 3rd table which has its own unique id (primary key) column.