# Get intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, python

I want to get the intersecting (common) rows across two 2D numpy arrays. E.g., if the following arrays are passed as inputs:

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

the output should be:

```
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6])
```

I know how to do this with loops. I'm looking at a Pythonic/Numpy way to do this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For short arrays, using sets is probably the clearest and most readable way to do it.

Another way is to use [`numpy.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html).  You'll have to trick it into treating the rows as a single value, though... This makes things a bit less readable...

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])
B = np.array([[1,4],[3,6],[7,8]])

nrows, ncols = A.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
       'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}

C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))

# This last bit is optional if you're okay with "C" being a structured array...
C = C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
```

For large arrays, this should be considerably faster than using sets.

Comment: Would `np.intersect1d(a, b).reshape(-1, ncols)` achieve the same result?

Comment: Scratch the earlier comment... You're quite right... It should work in all cases.

Comment: Actually, no, it won't work.  (I realized that earlier, and then forgot it!) Without the structured dtype, it doesn't consider things as rows, just the "raw" numbers. Consider something like `A = np.array([[4,1],[2,5],[3,6]])` and `B = np.array([[1,4],[3,6],[7,8]])`.

Comment: I tried to use this, but it doesn't seem to work for me in python 2.6.5.

Comment: @Karthik - Do you get a `ValueError: zero length field name in format`? I've used new-style string formatting. On python2.6, you'll need to put `'names':['f{0}'.format....` instead of `'names':['f{}'.format...`

Comment: You can replace that dtype line with: `dtype = (', '.join([str(A.dtype)]*ncols))`. the name is not specified, so it defaults to f0, f1, etc.

Comment: I know It is already years ago. I wonder how could you shed a light on me for my similar questions. But my A and B have different length, and also I want to find the corresponding index of A and B, not the common elements themselves. Thanks.

Comment: The link of my question is: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214903/get-intersect-indexes-across-two-2d-or-3d-numpy-arrays`

Answer (score 23):

You could use Python's sets:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])
>>> B = np.array([[1,4],[3,6],[7,8]])
>>> aset = set([tuple(x) for x in A])
>>> bset = set([tuple(x) for x in B])
>>> np.array([x for x in aset & bset])
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

As Rob Cowie points out, this can be done more concisely as

```
np.array([x for x in set(tuple(x) for x in A) & set(tuple(x) for x in B)])
```

There's probably a way to do this without all the going back and forth from arrays to tuples, but it's not coming to me right now.

Comment: I concur. Can't find any 'native' numpy way of doing it. One-line version might be `common = set(tuple(i) for i in A) & set(tuple(i) for i in B)`

Comment: If you're going to use set you can use the intersection function: set.intersection( aset, bset)

Comment: @rhinoinrepose - is using the function faster than `&` ?

Answer (score 12):

I could not understand why there is no suggested pure numpy way to get this working. So I found one, that uses numpy broadcast. The basic idea is to transform one of the arrays to 3d by axes swapping. Let's construct 2 arrays:

```
a=np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))
b=np.zeros_like(a)
b[:4,:]=a[np.random.randint(a.shape[0], size=4), :]
```

With my run it gave:

```
a=array([[5, 6, 3],
   [8, 1, 0],
   [2, 1, 4],
   [8, 0, 6],
   [6, 7, 6]])
b=array([[2, 1, 4],
   [2, 1, 4],
   [6, 7, 6],
   [5, 6, 3],
   [0, 0, 0]])
```

The steps are (arrays can be interchanged) :

```
#a is nxm and b is kxm
c = np.swapaxes(a[:,:,None],1,2)==b #transform a to nx1xm
# c has nxkxm dimensions due to comparison broadcast
# each nxixj slice holds comparison matrix between a[j,:] and b[i,:]
# Decrease dimension to nxk with product:
c = np.prod(c,axis=2)
#To get around duplicates://
# Calculate cumulative sum in k-th dimension
c= c*np.cumsum(c,axis=0)
# compare with 1, so that to get only one 'True' statement by row
c=c==1
#//
# sum in k-th dimension, so that a nx1 vector is produced
c=np.sum(c,axis=1).astype(bool)
# The intersection between a and b is a[c]
result=a[c]
```

In a function with 2 lines for used memory reduction (correct me if wrong):

```
def array_row_intersection(a,b):
   tmp=np.prod(np.swapaxes(a[:,:,None],1,2)==b,axis=2)
   return a[np.sum(np.cumsum(tmp,axis=0)*tmp==1,axis=1).astype(bool)]
```

which gave result for my example:

```
result=array([[5, 6, 3],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [6, 7, 6]])
```

This is faster than set solutions, as it makes use only of simple numpy operations, while it reduces constantly dimensions, and is ideal for two big matrices. I guess I might have made mistakes in my comments, as I got the answer by experimentation and instinct. The equivalent for column intersection can either be found by transposing the arrays or by changing the steps a little. Also, if duplicates are wanted, then the steps inside "//" have to be skipped. The function can be edited to return only the boolean array of the indices, which came handy to me ,while trying to get different arrays indices with the same vector. Benchmark for the voted answer and mine (number of elements in each dimension plays role on what to choose):

Code:

```
def voted_answer(A,B):
    nrows, ncols = A.shape
    dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
           'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}
    C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))
    return C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)

a_small=np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
b_small=np.zeros_like(a_small)
b_small=a_small[np.random.randint(a_small.shape[0],size=[a_small.shape[0]]),:]
a_big_row=np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 1000))
b_big_row=a_big_row[np.random.randint(a_big_row.shape[0],size=[a_big_row.shape[0]]),:]
a_big_col=np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 10))
b_big_col=a_big_col[np.random.randint(a_big_col.shape[0],size=[a_big_col.shape[0]]),:]
a_big_all=np.random.randint(10, size=(100,100))
b_big_all=a_big_all[np.random.randint(a_big_all.shape[0],size=[a_big_all.shape[0]]),:]



print 'Small arrays:'
print '\t Voted answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:voted_answer(a_small,b_small),number=100)/100
print '\t Proposed answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:array_row_intersection(a_small,b_small),number=100)/100
print 'Big column arrays:'
print '\t Voted answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:voted_answer(a_big_col,b_big_col),number=100)/100
print '\t Proposed answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:array_row_intersection(a_big_col,b_big_col),number=100)/100
print 'Big row arrays:'
print '\t Voted answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:voted_answer(a_big_row,b_big_row),number=100)/100
print '\t Proposed answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:array_row_intersection(a_big_row,b_big_row),number=100)/100
print 'Big arrays:'
print '\t Voted answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:voted_answer(a_big_all,b_big_all),number=100)/100
print '\t Proposed answer:',timeit.timeit(lambda:array_row_intersection(a_big_all,b_big_all),number=100)/100
```

with results:

```
Small arrays:
     Voted answer: 7.47108459473e-05
     Proposed answer: 2.47001647949e-05
Big column arrays:
     Voted answer: 0.00198730945587
     Proposed answer: 0.0560171294212
Big row arrays:
     Voted answer: 0.00500325918198
     Proposed answer: 0.000308241844177
Big arrays:
     Voted answer: 0.000864889621735
     Proposed answer: 0.00257176160812
```

Following verdict is that if you have to compare 2 big 2d arrays of 2d points  then use voted answer. If you have big matrices in all dimensions, voted answer is the best one by all means. So, it depends on what you choose each time.

Comment: Getting ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds for 'c = np.prod(c,axis=2)' line

Comment: That's weird, c is supposed to have 3 dimensions, by issuing the command `c = np.swapaxes(a[:,:,None],1,2)==b' ....

Comment: very neat. it is also possible to return indices with a small modification. `np.where(np.prod(np.swapaxes(Array_A[:,:,None],1,2) == Array_B,axis=2).astype(bool))`

Answer (score 11):

#### [`Numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

We can create a boolean mask using broadcasting which can be then used to filter the rows in array `A` which are also present in array `B`

```
A = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])
B = np.array([[1,4],[3,6],[7,8]])

m = (A[:, None] == B).all(-1).any(1)
```

---

```
>>> A[m]

array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to achieve this using structured array:

```
>>> a = np.array([[3, 1, 2], [5, 8, 9], [7, 4, 3]])
>>> b = np.array([[2, 3, 0], [3, 1, 2], [7, 4, 3]])
>>> av = a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1]).ravel()
>>> bv = b.view([('', b.dtype)] * b.shape[1]).ravel()
>>> np.intersect1d(av, bv).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
array([[3, 1, 2],
       [7, 4, 3]])
```

Just for clarity, the structured view looks like this:

```
>>> a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1])
array([[(3, 1, 2)],
       [(5, 8, 9)],
       [(7, 4, 3)]],
       dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8')])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.array(set(map(tuple, b)).difference(set(map(tuple, a))))
```

This could also work

Answer (score 2):

```
A = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])
B = np.array([[1,4],[3,6],[7,8]])

def matching_rows(A,B):
  matches=[i for i in range(B.shape[0]) if np.any(np.all(A==B[i],axis=1))]
  if len(matches)==0:
    return B[matches]
  return np.unique(B[matches],axis=0)

>>> matching_rows(A,B)
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

This of course assumes the rows are all the same length.

Answer (score 2):

**Without Index**
Visit https://gist.github.com/RashidLadj/971c7235ce796836853fcf55b4876f3c

```
def intersect2D(Array_A, Array_B):
"""
Find row intersection between 2D numpy arrays, a and b.
"""

# ''' Using Tuple ''' #
intersectionList = list(set([tuple(x) for x in Array_A for y in Array_B  if(tuple(x) == tuple(y))]))
print ("intersectionList = \n",intersectionList)

# ''' Using Numpy function "array_equal" ''' #
""" This method is valid for an ndarray """
intersectionList = list(set([tuple(x) for x in Array_A for y in Array_B  if(np.array_equal(x, y))]))
print ("intersectionList = \n",intersectionList)

# ''' Using set and bitwise and '''
intersectionList = [list(y) for y in (set([tuple(x) for x in Array_A]) & set([tuple(x) for x in Array_B]))]
print ("intersectionList = \n",intersectionList)

return intersectionList
```

**With Index**
Visit https://gist.github.com/RashidLadj/bac71f3d3380064de2f9abe0ae43c19e

```
def intersect2D(Array_A, Array_B):
  """
  Find row intersection between 2D numpy arrays, a and b.
  Returns another numpy array with shared rows and index of items in A & B arrays
  """
  # [[IDX], [IDY], [value]] where Equal
  # ''' Using Tuple ''' #
  IndexEqual = np.asarray([(i, j, x) for i,x in enumerate(Array_A) for j, y in enumerate (Array_B)  if(tuple(x) == tuple(y))]).T
  
  # ''' Using Numpy array_equal ''' #
  IndexEqual = np.asarray([(i, j, x) for i,x in enumerate(Array_A) for j, y in enumerate (Array_B)  if(np.array_equal(x, y))]).T
  
  idx, idy, intersectionList = (IndexEqual[0], IndexEqual[1], IndexEqual[2]) if len(IndexEqual) != 0 else ([], [], [])

  return intersectionList, idx, idy
```

Answer (score 1):

All the mentioned methods are slow when it comes to very large arrays. I found a way to do it using numpy. Since numpy only provides [np.in1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) for 1D arrays, we can encode the 2D array to 1D array using [cantor pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way) in axis 1. Then the numpy's function can be used.

```
def cantor_pairing(a, b):
    return (a + b) * (a + b + 1) / 2 + a

def intersecting_indices(a, b):

    pair_a = cantor_pairing(cantor_pairing(a[:,0], a[:, 1]), a[:, 2])
    pair_b = cantor_pairing(cantor_pairing(b[:,0], b[:, 1]), b[:, 2])

    boolean_array = np.in1d(pair_a, pair_b)
    intersected_indices = np.where(bool_array==True)[0]

    return intersected_indices
```

This is the fastest possible way for very large arrays.
One important thing to remember is that cantor pairing can only be done for non-negative integers. So if you have negative integers in your arrays, make them all positive before using it (by adding the min value).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

B=np.array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6],
       [7, 8]])

intersetingRows=[(B==irow).all(axis=1).any() for irow in A]
print(A[intersetingRows])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using the numpy.intersect function along with the axis parameter set to 0 to find the common rows across two 2D numpy arrays. Here's an example:

```
      import numpy as np

     # Define the input arrays
array1 = np.array([[1, 4],
                   [2, 5],
                   [3, 6]])

array2 = np.array([[1, 4],
                   [3, 6],
                   [7, 8]])

# Find the intersecting rows
result = np.intersect1d(array1, array2, assume_unique=True)

# Reshape the result back into 2D array
result = result.reshape(-1, array1.shape[1])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1 4]
 [3 6]]
```

In this example, np.intersect1d is used to find the common elements between array1 and array2. assume_unique=True is used for performance optimization when it is known that the input arrays are unique.

Then, result is reshaped back into a 2D array to get the final output.

This approach provides a more Pythonic/Numpy way to find the intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays without using explicit loops.