# Set value based on day in month in pandas timeseries

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a timeseries

```
date    
2009-12-23    0.0
2009-12-28    0.0
2009-12-29    0.0
2009-12-30    0.0
2009-12-31    0.0
2010-01-04    0.0
2010-01-05    0.0
2010-01-06    0.0
2010-01-07    0.0
2010-01-08    0.0
2010-01-11    0.0
2010-01-12    0.0
2010-01-13    0.0
2010-01-14    0.0
2010-01-15    0.0
2010-01-18    0.0
2010-01-19    0.0
2010-01-20    0.0
2010-01-21    0.0
2010-01-22    0.0
2010-01-25    0.0
2010-01-26    0.0
2010-01-27    0.0
2010-01-28    0.0
2010-01-29    0.0
2010-02-01    0.0
2010-02-02    0.0
```

I would like to set the value to 1 based on the following rule:

- If the constant is set 9 this means the 9th of each month. Due to
  that that 2010-01-09 doesn't exist I would like to set the next date
  that exists in the series to 1 which is 2010-01-11 above.

I have tried to create two series one (series1) with day < 9 set to 1 and one (series2) with day > 9 to 1 and then `series1.shift(1) * series2`
It works in the middle of the month but not if day is set to 1 due to that the last date in previous month is set to 0 in series1.

Comment: Usually, it'll help to have one question per post, and having expected output with your attempt of the problem is appreciated.

Comment: OK! I will edit the post so it only contains one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your timeseries is `s` with a datetimeindex

I want to create a `groupby` object of all index values whose days are greater than or equal to `9`.

```
g = s.index.to_series().dt.day.ge(9).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))
```

Then I'll check that there is at least one day past `>= 9` and grab the first among them.  With those, I'll assign the value of 1.

```
s.loc[g.idxmax()[g.any()]] = 1
s

date
2009-12-23    1.0
2009-12-28    0.0
2009-12-29    0.0
2009-12-30    0.0
2009-12-31    0.0
2010-01-04    0.0
2010-01-05    0.0
2010-01-06    0.0
2010-01-07    0.0
2010-01-08    0.0
2010-01-11    1.0
2010-01-12    0.0
2010-01-13    0.0
2010-01-14    0.0
2010-01-15    0.0
2010-01-18    0.0
2010-01-19    0.0
2010-01-20    0.0
2010-01-21    0.0
2010-01-22    0.0
2010-01-25    0.0
2010-01-26    0.0
2010-01-27    0.0
2010-01-28    0.0
2010-01-29    0.0
2010-02-01    0.0
2010-02-02    0.0
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Note that `2009-12-23` also was assigned a `1` as it satisfies this requirement as well.

Comment: This is pretty smart!

Comment: <offtopic> @piRSquared, have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727332/) - i was trying to find a vectorized solution and have failed. I think it's pretty challenging ... ;-) </offtopic>

Comment: @MaxU I had not seen that.  That will give me something to think about on my drive as I'm about to leave in a few minutes.  I'll give it a go, thx for sharing that with me.