# Find conected elements (runs) in a 3D array for a given direction

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array, for example:

```
array = np.array([[[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
                  [[1.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
                  [[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

I need to find the runs of conected ones for each possible size for different directions. 
For example, in the direction (1,0,0), horitzontal direction, the output should be:

```
> **Runs of size 1: 2
> **Runs of size 2: 1
> **Runs of size 3: 0
```

On the direction (0, 1, 0), accross the vertical axis:

```
> **Runs of size 1: 4
> **Runs of size 2: 0
> **Runs of size 3: 0
```

And in the direction (0, 0, 1), accross the z axis:

```
> **Runs of size 1: 1
> **Runs of size 2: 0
> **Runs of size 3: 1
```

Is there an effective way to implement this?

**EDIT:**

I attach the solution I am working on:

```
dire = np.array(([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1])) # Possible directions
results = np.zeros((array.shape[0], len(dire)))  # Maximum runs will be 3

# Find all indices
indices = np.argwhere(array == 1) 

# Loop over each direction                 
for idire, dire in enumerate(dire):
    results[0, idire] = np.count_nonzero(array) # Count all 1 (conection 0)
    indices_to_compare = indices    

# Now we compare the list of indices with a displaced list of indices
    for irun in range(1, array.shape[0]):   
        indices_displaced = indices + dire*irun             
        aset = set([tuple(x) for x in indices_displaced])
        bset = set([tuple(x) for x in indices_to_compare])
        indices_to_compare = (np.array([x for x in aset & bset]))
        results[irun, idire] = len(indices_to_compare)

    # Rest the counts off bigger runs to the smaller ones, for duplicates
    for indx in np.arange(array.shape[0]-2,-1,-1):
        results[indx, idire] -=            
        np.sum(results[np.arange(array.shape[0]-1,indx,-1), idire])


print(results) # Each column is a direction, each row is the number of bins.

> [[ 2.  4.  3.]
   [ 1.  0.  1.]
   [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

So far this code does not work, only for the direction (0,1,0), which does not have any connection and it is trivial. With this notation, the expected output should be:

```
> [[ 2.  4.  1.]
   [ 1.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

The comparision of the arrays is from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays).

**EDIT 2:**

I had a mistake in the interpretation of the coordinates, it seems that addint to the results of `np.argwhere`, (1,0,0) is over the z axist, so the expected result should be:

```
> [[ 1.  4.  2.]
   [ 0.  0.  1.]
   [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: array.tranpose() may be useful . That said, you should show any attempts you have so far.

Comment: Are those max. runs, because each element along the dims that are not reduced would have some run value? Shows us your best effort, maybe a loopy code to help us get some sense of the problem?

Comment: I am really stuck at this problem. I tried to start with loops, but I am able to find if there is a 1 conected, but not the size of the conection. So far my code is not worth to post.

Comment: What if the direction is `(-1,0,1)`? Do you need to support non-axial directions? If not, a simpler api would be to pass `axis=n`

Comment: Yes, in theory all directions are possible

Comment: I imagine there's a solution using `cumsum` to count them,  some clever boolean masking, and `bincoint` to group them - but that'll only work for axial directions.

Comment: I think its possible to turn a non-axial problem into an axial one by padding the array with enough zeros, and then using `as_strided

Comment: I added the approach I was working, I do know if it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a variation of the code I was working in that now it seems it works:

```
import numpy as np


array = np.array([[[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
                  [[1.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
                  [[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])

dire = np.array(([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1])) # Possible directions
results = np.zeros((array.shape[0], len(dire)))  # Maximum runs will be 3

# Find all indices
indices = np.argwhere(array == 1) 

# Loop over each direction                 
for idire, dire in enumerate(dire):
    results[0, idire] = len(indices) # Count all 1 (conection 0)
    indices_to_compare = indices 

    for irun in range(1, array.shape[0]):
        print('dir:',dire, 'run', irun)
        indices_displaced = indices + dire*irun             
        aset = set([tuple(x) for x in indices_displaced])
        bset = set([tuple(x) for x in indices_to_compare])
        indices_to_compare = (np.array([x for x in aset & bset]))
        results[irun, idire] = len(indices_to_compare)


    for iindx in np.arange(array.shape[0]-2,-1,-1):
        for jindx in np.arange(iindx+1, array.shape[0]):
            print(iindx,jindx,  results[jindx, idire])
            results[iindx, idire] -=  results[jindx, idire] *(jindx-iindx+1)         


print('\n',results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution that works along an axial direction:

```
def run_lengths(arr, axis):
    # convert to boolean, for speed - no need to store 0 and 1 as floats
    arr = arr.astype(bool)

    # move the axis in question to the start, to make the slicing below easy
    arr = np.moveaxis(arr, axis, 0)

    # find positions at the start and end of a run
    first = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
    first[:1] = arr[:1]
    first[1:] = arr[1:] & ~arr[:-1]
    last = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
    last[-1:] = arr[-1]
    last[:-1] = arr[:-1] & ~arr[1:]

    # count the number in each run
    c = np.cumsum(arr, axis=0)
    lengths = c[last] - c[first]

    # group the runs by length. Note the above gives 0 for a run of length 1,
    # so result[i] is the number of runs of length (i + 1)
    return np.bincount(lengths, minlength=len(arr))

for i in range(3):
    print(run_lengths(array, axis=i))
```

```
[1 0 1]
[4 0 0]
[2 1 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works in any direction and combination of directions. Essentially, we use the array to create a graph in which True elements correspond to nodes and edges are created if there is a node in any of the allowed directions. We then compute the connected components and their sizes. Uses [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) to find the connected components in the graph, which is easily installed via pip.

```
 import numpy as np
 import networkx

 def array_to_graph(bool_array, allowed_steps):
     """
     Arguments:
     ----------
     bool_array    -- boolean array
     allowed_steps -- list of allowed steps; e.g. given a 2D boolean array,
                      [(0, 1), (1, 1)] signifies that from coming from element
                      (i, j) only elements (i, j+1) and (i+1, j+1) are reachable

     Returns:
     --------
     g               -- networkx.DiGraph() instance
     position_to_idx -- dict mapping (i, j) position to node idx
     idx_to_position -- dict mapping node idx to (i, j) position
     """

     # ensure that bool_array is boolean
     assert bool_array.dtype == np.bool, "Input array has to be boolean!"

     # map array indices to node indices and vice versa
     node_idx = range(np.sum(bool_array))
     node_positions = zip(*np.where(bool_array))
     position_to_idx = dict(zip(node_positions, node_idx))

     # create graph
     g = networkx.DiGraph()
     for source in node_positions:
         for step in allowed_steps: # try to step in all allowed directions
             target = tuple(np.array(source) + np.array(step))
             if target in position_to_idx:
                 g.add_edge(position_to_idx[source], position_to_idx[target])

     idx_to_position = dict(zip(node_idx, node_positions))

     return g, idx_to_position, position_to_idx

 def get_connected_component_sizes(g):
     component_generator = networkx.connected_components(g)
     component_sizes = [len(component) for component in component_generator]
     return component_sizes

 def test():
     array = np.array([[[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
                        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
                       [[1.,  0.,  0.],
                        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
                       [[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
                        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]], dtype=np.bool)

     directions = [(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)]

     for direction in directions:
         graph, _, _ = array_to_graph(array, [direction])
         sizes = get_connected_component_sizes(graph.to_undirected())
         counts = np.bincount(sizes)

         print direction
         for ii, c in enumerate(counts):
             if ii > 1:
                 print "Runs of size {}: {}".format(ii, c)

     return
```

**NOTE**: "Runs" of size 1 are not counted (correctly) but I presume you are not that interested in them anyway. Otherwise, you can easily compute them ex-post by computing the total number of True elements in the particular direction and subtracting number of runs times run length.

Comment: `zip(*np.where(...))` is better spelt `argwhere`, and then you can change `map(operator.add, source, step)` to just `source + np.array(step)`

Comment: I need to do another dictionary lookup though: `g.add_edge(position_to_idx[source], position_to_idx[target])` and arrays are not hashable.... (although I agree in principle that the line is question is ugly).

Comment: Right, you still need the tuple conversion, but you can at least ditch the `map`

Comment: It does not work in my computer. The variable sizes (and counts) is empty.

Comment: Weird. Can you add the following line after the graph is created:  `print list(graph.nodes()), list(graph.edges())` and tell me the output? Which python version are you running?