# How to make Numpy treat each row/tensor as a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, n-dimensional

Many functions like [`in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [`setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) are designed for 1-d array. One workaround to apply these methods on N-dimensional arrays is to make `numpy` to treat each row  (something more high dimensional) as a value.

One approach I found to do so is in this answer [Get intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays/8317403#8317403) by Joe Kington.

The following code is taken from this answer. The task Joe Kington faced was to detect common rows in two arrays `A` and `B` while trying to use `in1d`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])
B = np.array([[1,4],[3,6],[7,8]])

nrows, ncols = A.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
       'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}

C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))

# This last bit is optional if you're okay with "C" being a structured array...
C = C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
```

I am hoping you to help me with any of the following three questions. First, I do not understand the mechanisms behind this method. Can you try to explain it to me?

Second, is there other ways to let numpy treat an subarray as one object?

One more open question: dose Joe's approach have any drawbacks? I mean whether treating rows as a value might cause some problems? Sorry this question is pretty broad.

Comment: to extend your query one step more, examine 'isin' in numpy 1.13.  For example:   np.isin(a.view(dtype), b.view(dtype)) which yields array([[ True],  [False],  [ True]], dtype=bool).  Without the dtype you get a position test... np.isin(a, b)
... yields  array([[ True,  True],  [False, False],  [ True,  True]], type=bool)

Comment: @NaN Cool. What's your `a`, `b` and `dtype`?

Comment: Do you understand structured arrays?  Joe's answer is a generalization of Ram Kumar Karn's.  `A.view(dtype)` is a 1d array whose elements contain all the bytes of one row of `A`.  `intersect1d` apparently doesn't care how big the elements are as long as they can be compared.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried to read some more early on tonight. I think I have a feeling about why it works.

Comment: Another approach is to use broadcasting to compare the arrays element by element (creating a higher dimensional boolean array), and then use some combination of  `any` and `all` to reduce one or more of the axes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for offering the method! I was actually asking about other ways to do Joe's trick but this is also helpful! Though, I think structure arrays might be the only way to achieve this. (Not knowing.) Thank you for help clarifying my question.

Comment: @Tai, I just used lower-case for your A and B and the dtype was therefore the same as yours.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @NaN Got you. No problems. Got you :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to post what I have learned. The method Joe used is called [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays). It will allow users to define what is contained in a single cell/element.

We take a look at the description of the first example the documentation provided.

> ```
> x = np.array([(1,2.,'Hello'), (2,3.,"World")], ...  
>               dtype=[('foo', 'i4'),('bar', 'f4'), ('baz', 'S10')])
> ```
>
> Here we have created a **one-dimensional** array of **length 2**. **Each element
>   of this array is a structure that contains three items**, a 32-bit
>   integer, a 32-bit float, and a string of length 10 or less.

Without passing in `dtype`, however, we will get a 2 by 3 matrix.

With this method, we would be able to let `numpy` treat a higher dimensional array as an single element with properly set `dtype`.

---

Another trick Joe showed is that we don't need to really form a new numpy array to achieve the purpose. We can use the `view` function (See [`ndarray.view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)) to change the way `numpy` view data. There is a section of `Note` section in [`ndarray.view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) that I think you should take a look before utilizing the method. **I have no guarantee that there would not be side effects.** The paragraph below is from the note section and seems to call for caution.

> For a.view(some_dtype), if some_dtype has a different number of bytes per entry than the previous dtype (*for example, converting a regular array to a structured array*), **then the behavior of the view cannot be predicted just from the superficial appearance of a (shown by print(a))**. It also depends on exactly how a is stored in memory. Therefore if a is C-ordered versus fortran-ordered, versus defined as a slice or transpose, etc., the view may give different results.

Other reference

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html