# Find arrays of ndarray that are in another ndarray - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there's any built-in method to find arrays of a ndarray that are contained into another ndarray.
i.e.

```
arr1 = [[1,2], [2,9], [3,7], [5,11], [32,5], [11,4], [89,3], [37,5]]
```

and

```
arr2 = [[12,44], [2,9], [125,3], [37,5]]
```

I would like to know if there's any built-in method to identify that `[2,9]` and `[37,5]` are the only arrays of `arr2` contained into `arr1`. Or to identify their indexes.

Comment: Why don't you try `[x for x in arr1 if x in arr2]` This will not give the indexes, but the elements themselves.

Comment: Just use a list comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sets and tuples, to do this, using:

```
arr1 = [[1,2], [2,9], [3,7], [5,11], [32,5], [11,4], [89,3], [37,5]]
arr2 = [[12,44], [2,9], [125,3], [37,5]]

set1 = {tuple(i) for i in arr1}
set2 = {tuple(i) for i in arr2}

arr3 = [list(i) for i in set1 & set2]
```

But it would be much simpler just to use a list comprehension

```
arr3 = [i for i in arr1 if i in arr2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use sets:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,"B"]
b = [2, "B", 5]
sa = set(a)
sb = set(b)
c = list(sa.intersection(sb))
```

`c` will be:

```
[2, "B"]
```

Comment: it will work whatever the types in the original arrays

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use intersection of rows of the 2 lists, after mapping each row to `tuple`.

The reason why conversion to `tuple` is necessary is because tuples are immutable and hashable. Therefore, they can be included in a `set`, while lists cannot.

```
arr1 = [[1,2], [2,9], [3,7], [5,11], [32,5], [11,4], [89,3], [37,5]]
arr2 = [[12,44], [2,9], [125,3], [37,5]]

res = set(map(tuple, arr1)) & set(map(tuple, arr2))

# {(2, 9), (37, 5)}
```

If required, convert the result back to lists:

```
res2 = list(map(list, res))

# [[37, 5], [2, 9]]
```

Alternative, possibly more efficient, solutions if `numpy` arrays are viable:

1. [Get intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays)
2. [Find arrays of ndarray that are in another ndarray - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466238/find-arrays-of-ndarray-that-are-in-another-ndarray-python)