# Search a 2D array in another 2D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays. Eg.

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
B = [[5,6],[1,4],[6,5],[1,2]]
```

I want to get the matching elements in the 2 arrays.
i.e `[[1,2],[5,6]]`

The arrays that I am using in my code are very large. Is there any fast way of implementing it, without using for loop and comparing each elements?

Comment: isn't there some sort of "intersection" function thing?

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
B = [[5,6],[1,4],[6,5],[1,2]]

print([x for x in A if x in B])
# [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
B = [[5,6],[1,4],[6,5],[1,2]]

print([x for x in A if x in B])
```