# How to find the indexes of arrays nested in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the most efficient way to get the indexes of nested arrays in another array.

```
import numpy as np
#                     0     1      2     3
haystack = np.array([[1,3],[3,4,],[5,6],[7,8]])
needles  = np.array([[3,4],[7,8]])
```

Given the arrays contained in `needles` I want to find their indexes in `haystack`. In this case 1,3.

I came up with this solution:

```
 indexes = [idx for idx,elem in enumerate(haystack) if elem in needles ]
```

Which is **wrong** because actually is sufficient that one element in `elem` is in `needles` to return the `idx`.

Is there any faster alternative?

Comment: `indexes = [idx for idx,elem in enumerate(needles) if elem in haystack ]`

This gets indexes in needles, not haystack!

Answer (score 0):

this response gives a solution to a similar problem [Get intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays), you use the `np.in1d`  function which is pretty efficient, but you do that by giving it a view of both arrays which allows is to process them as 1d data array.
In your case, you could do

```py
A = np.array([[1,3],[3,4,],[5,6],[7,8]])
B = np.array([[3,4],[7,8]])
nrows, ncols = A.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
       'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}
indexes, = np.where(np.in1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype)))
```

which outputs :

```
print(indexes)
> array([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
indices = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.where(np.isin(haystack, x).sum(axis=1)==2)[0], 1, needles).flatten()
indices
>>> array([1, 3])
```