# find indices of matching rows in 2d array without loop (one shot)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search, 2d

I want to find multiple matching rows from 2d array a

```
a = np.array([[2, 1],
          [3, 3],
          [4, 6],
          [4, 8],
          [4, 7],
          [4, 3]])
```

I have to search following entries

```
 b = np.array([[4,6],
          [4,7]])
```

I know that I can loop over b and do following

```
for i in range(len(b)) :
   print(np.where(np.all(a==b[i],axis=1))[0])
```

And I get following

```
[2]
[4]
```

Can I get [[2],[4]] directly **without using any loop**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the indices you will generally reach for the `arg_x` functions like `argmax` and `argwhere`. Here [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) will give you the indices if you can figure out how to pass the correct list of booleans. You can do that with [np.isin()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html?highlight=isin#numpy.isin):

```
a = np.array([[2, 1],
          [3, 3],
          [4, 6],
          [4, 8],
          [4, 7],
          [4, 3]])

b = np.array([[4,6], [4,7]])

np.argwhere(np.isin(a, b).all(axis=1))
```

Which returns:

```
array([[2],
       [4]])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, elegant and simple to understand. thanks !

Comment: I believe this works by chance (since the second row contains only unique elements), doesnt it? If the first row was [2,6] this would also match it and return the 0 index

Comment: You are a savior. Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer is wrong and should not be accepted ! `np.isin()` check each elements individually. For example if the row `[6,7]` is present in `a` then this row will be returned as a matching row !

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fast solution noticing that the two pairs have the same first coordinate:

```
np.where((a[:, 0] == 4) & ((a[:, 1] == 6) | (a[:, 1] == 7)))  
# Out:
# (array([2, 4]),)
```

The expression

```
print((a[:, 0] == 4) & ((a[:, 1] == 6) | (a[:, 1] == 7)))
```

gives

```
[False False  True False  True False]
```