# Union of 2d array in Python by row according to first column

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find a union of two 2d arrays based on the first column:

```
>>> x1
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> x2
array([[ 7, -1, -1],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

If two rows have a matching first value, I want the one from `x2`. I.e. the union of the first column of `x1[:, 0]` and `x2[:, 0]` is `[1, 4, 7, 10]` and I want the row `[7, -1, -1]` from `x2`, **not** `[7, 8, 9]` from `x1`. The expected result in this case is:

```
>>> res
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7, -1, -1],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

I see there is a possible solution for union of a 2D array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays), where I get the result:

```
>>> res
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7, -1, -1],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

In this result, I wanted the row `[7, 8, 9]` from `x1` to be excluded. How could I do that?

Comment: What does `where the row from x2 is preferred` mean?

Comment: Having all 5 rows is the union of both arrays. Why would you take [7, -1, -1] over [7, 8, 9]? Are you saying that you want the first number of each row to be unique? If so, why not just iterate over them, deleting any row that contains a number in row[0] that you've already encountered.

Comment: I think it should also be ok to delete intersections of row 0 in x1 and row_stack x1 and x2

Comment: What if rows are duplicated within the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), placing `x2` first. Unique can compute the index of your values, based on the first occurrence:

```
values = np.concatenate((x2[:, 0], x1[:, 0]))
_, index = np.unique(values, return_index=True)
mask = index >= x2.shape[0]
result = np.concatenate((x1[index[mask] - x2.shape[0], :], x2[index[~mask], :]), axis=0)
```

The result is exactly the array you would expect:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7, -1, -1],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Keep in mind that the result of `unique` is sorted, which coincidentally happens to correspond to your original order. You can get the original order with a clever application of `return_inverse=True`, which will be left as an exercise for the reader.