# Hot to get the set difference of two 2d numpy arrays, or equivalent of np.setdiff1d in a 2d array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, set-difference

Here [Get intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays) they got intersecting rows by using the function `np.intersect1d`. So i changed the function to use `np.setdiff1d` to get the set difference but it doesn't work properly. The following is the code.

```
def set_diff2d(A, B):
    nrows, ncols = A.shape
    dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
          'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}
    C = np.setdiff1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))

    return C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
```

The following data is used for checking the issue:

```
min_dis=400
Xt = np.arange(50, 3950, min_dis)
Yt = np.arange(50, 3950, min_dis)

Xt, Yt = np.meshgrid(Xt, Yt)
Xt[::2] += min_dis/2
# This is the super set
turbs_possible_locs = np.vstack([Xt.flatten(), Yt.flatten()]).T
# This is the subset
subset = turbs_possible_locs[np.random.choice(turbs_possible_locs.shape[0],50, replace=False)]
diffs = set_diff2d(turbs_possible_locs, subset)
```

`diffs` is supposed to have a shape of 50x2, but it is not.

Comment: Can you share sample data for which you see it failing?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I've added the code to reproduce the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to fix your issue try the following tweak:

```py
def set_diff2d(A, B):
    nrows, ncols = A.shape
    dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)], 'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}
    C = np.setdiff1d(A.copy().view(dtype), B.copy().view(dtype))
    return C
```

The problem was - `A` after `.view(...)` was applied was broken in half - so it had 2 `tuple` columns, instead of 1, like `B`. I.e. as a consequence of applying `dtype` you essentially collapsed 2 columns into `tuple` - which is why you could do the intersection in 1d in the first place.

Quoting after documentation:

"

a.view(some_dtype) or a.view(dtype=some_dtype) constructs a view of the array’s memory with a different data-type. This can cause a reinterpretation of the bytes of memory.

"

Src https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html

I think the "reinterpretation" is exactly what happened - hence for the sake of simplicity I would just `.copy()` the array.

**NB** however I wouldn't square it - it's always `A` which gets 'broken' - whether it's an assignment, or inline `B` is always fine...

Comment: I just realized, since I generate the superset in the code I can work with the first index of the numpy array which is in 1d, thus all the 1d operations can be applied. The problem I stated here, which is when we simply have two arrays without any superset to get and index, can be solved by this answer.