# Can I remove rows all similar rows from one 2d array, to another 2d array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to remove all rows that overlap, but I cannot find a way to do it.

If

```
a= ([1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8])
b= ([3,4],[7,8])

k = np.delete (a,b,0)
```

I want something like that to work

I am expecting k = ([3,4],[7,8])

Comment: Please check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```py
result = [row for row in a if row  in b]

print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your answer may be correct, it's important to leave some explanation with it so that people can understand it better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this will be separated into 2 steps.
first you need to find the indices of rows in `a` that overlap with `b`.
this can be done this way:

```
overlap_indices = np.where(np.isin(a, b).all(axis=1))[0]
```

[1] **np.isin(a, b)**: returns a boolean array of the same shape as a, where each element is True if the corresponding element of a is present in b, and False otherwise, in your case:

```
[[False False]
[ True  True]
[False False]
[ True  True]]
```

[2] **.all(axis=1)**: returns a Boolean array of size **a.shape[0]** indicates the rows that all it's elements are True, in your case:

```
[False  True False  True]
```

[3] **np.where()** : eturns the indices of True values in the boolean array obtained by the **.all(axis=1)**, The resulting array is a tuple containing a single element :

```
(array([1, 3]),)
```

and the **[0]** selects the one and only element in that tuple:

```
[1 3]
```

then you can use the

```
k = np.delete(a, overlap_indices, axis=0)
```

that deletes the elements with the specified indices and returns them in k

```
print(k) # [[1 2] [5 6]]
```

sure that could be done using for loops, but this is a vectorized implementation that is much faster if the np array is large