# How can you represent a 2D array of arbitrarily sized dimensions?

Tags: ruby, arrays, data-structures, ruby-1.9, hash

What are some good ways to represent a 2D array that extends in arbitrary length in both dimensions?

Working in Ruby.

Comment: You can't have infinity.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What the OP probably meant is not infinity but arbitrarity. But disreagarding that, the OP's description is still contradictory: `2D` or `inifinite dimensions`; which?

Comment: @sawa - Yes, that is correct. It is 2 dimensions, each of arbitrary length.

Comment: Then, please correct both the title and the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a hash is good:

```
{
  [0, 0] => "A1",
  [1, 0] => "B1",
  ...
  [0, 1] => "A2",
  [1, 1] => "B2",
  ...
}
```

Or, to make it a less transparent but more efficient, you may think of a way to map a pair of numbers to a single number using a pairing function along the lines suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612), and use it as a key:

```
{
  0 => "A1",
  1 => "B1",
  ...
  2 => "A2",
  4 => "B2",
  ...
}
```