# Hash function for 2D point in limited Euclidean space

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I am storing a lot of objects with geographically positions as 2D points (x,y) in granularity of meters. To represent the world I am using a grid divided in cells of 1 square km. Currently I am using `HashMap<Position, Object>` for this. Any other map or appropriate data structure is fine, but I the solution works so I am only interested in solving the details.

I have been reading a lot about making good hash functions, specifically for 2D points. So far, no solutions have been really good (rated in terms of as collision-free as possible).

To test some ideas I wrote a very simple java program to generate hash codes for points from an arbitrary number (-1000,-1000) to (1000, 1000) (x1, y1 -> x2,y2) and storing them in a `HashSet<Integer>` and this is my result:

```
# java HashTest
4000000 number of unique positions
test1: 3936031 (63969 buckets, 1,60%) collisions using Objects.hash(x,y)
test2: 0 (4000000 buckets, 100,00%) collisions  using (x << 16) + y
test3: 3998000 (2000 buckets, 0,05%) collisions using x
test4: 3924037 (75963 buckets, 1,90%) collisions using x*37 + y
test5: 3996001 (3999 buckets, 0,10%) collisions using x*37 + y*37
test6: 3924224 (75776 buckets, 1,89%) collisions using x*37 ^ y
test7: 3899671 (100329 buckets, 2,51%) collisions using x*37 ^ y*37
test8: 0 (4000000 buckets, 100,00%) collisions using PerfectlyHashThem
test9: 0 (4000000 buckets, 100,00%) collisions using x << 16 | (y & 0xFFFF)
```

*Legend: number of collisions , buckets(collisions), perc(collisions)*

Most of these hash functions perform really bad. In fact, the only good solution is the one that shifts x to the first 16 bits of the integer. The limitation, I guess, is that the two most distant points must not be more than the square root of `Integer.MAX_INT`, i.e. area must be less than 46 340 square km.

This is my test function (just copied for each new hash function):

```
  public void test1() {

    HashSet<Integer> hashCodes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int collisions = 0;

    for (int x = -MAX_VALUE; x < MAX_VALUE; ++x) {
      for (int y = -MAX_VALUE; y < MAX_VALUE; ++y) {
        final int hashCode = Objects.hash(x,y);

        if (hashCodes.contains(hashCode))
          collisions++;

        hashCodes.add(hashCode);
      }
    }

    System.console().format("test1: %1$s (%2$s buckets, %3$.2f%%) collisions using Objects.hash(x,y)\n", collisions, buckets(collisions), perc(collisions));
  }
```

Am I thinking wrong here? Should I fine-tune the primes to get better results?

**Edits:**

Added more hash functions (test8 and test9). test8 comes from the reponse by @nawfal in [Mapping two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way) (converted from short to int).

Comment: I have tried with prime numbers 71 and 97 too now. Almost a double increase in number of buckets from 37.

Comment: Try 31, please. I'd like to see result.

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way.

Comment: For your numbers it should be possible to create 0 collisions. There's 4 billion different coordinates in -1000 to 1000 times -1000 to 1000. I think you're doing something wrong somewhere. Please post code.

Comment: 31 results in slightly "worse" than my example where I used 37. For instance:
test4: 3936031 (63969 buckets, 1,60%) collisions using x*31 + y

Comment: What would a better result be than no collisions at all?

Comment: No collisions would of course be the best. I'm just surprised by the number of collisions using some hash functions that seemed to be regarded as appropriate (such as the XOR /w prime).

Comment: But you're creating 2000*20000 entries into 76000 hashcodes (1000 or -1000 x 37 plus a bit is the largest and smallest hashcodes). Use my example, it guarantees zero collision. I'll edit it to allow for the ~20000 x 20000 grid.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void test1() {

    int MAX_VALUE = 1000;

    HashSet<Integer> hashCodes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int collisions = 0;

    for (int x = -MAX_VALUE; x < MAX_VALUE; ++x) {
        for (int y = -MAX_VALUE; y < MAX_VALUE; ++y) {
            final int hashCode = ((x+MAX_VALUE)<<16)|((y+MAX_VALUE)&0xFFFF);

            if (hashCodes.contains(hashCode))
                collisions++;

            hashCodes.add(hashCode);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Collisions: " + collisions + " // Buckets: " +  hashCodes.size());
}
```

Prints: Collisions: 0 // Buckets: 4000000

Comment: Thanks! Added it to the list of tests. It doesn't seem to differ much from test2, more than it truncates y to a short though?

Comment: It's probably close to the same, hmm. But what do you want more than no collisions?

Comment: I am more interested in knowing if the theory is correct. You can't see anything wrong with it, or how I am testing it?

Comment: What theory? Also, you don't say how you calculate your perc(collisions) and buckets(collision) or what they are. I assume buckets(collision) is the 2000x2000 - collisions just given a bad name?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I will update my post with an answer that seems to be perfect for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I a similar question with the answer being to use a Cantor pairing function. Here:
[Mapping two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way).

The Cantor pairing function can be used for negative integers as well, using bijection.