# Mapping function for two integers

Tags: algorithm, function

SO,

**The problem**

I have two integers, which are in first case, positive, and in second case - just any integers. I need to create a map function `F` from them to some another integer value, which will be:

- Result should be integer value. For first case (`x>0`, `y>0`), positive integer value
- Symmetric. That means F(x, y) = F(y, x)
- Unique. That means F(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) = F(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) <=> (x<sub>0</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> ^ y<sub>0</sub> = y<sub>1</sub>) V (y<sub>0</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> ^ x<sub>0</sub> = y<sub>1</sub>)

**My approach**

At first glance, for positive integers we could use expression like F(x, y) = x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>, but that will fail - for example, 89<sup>2</sup> + 23<sup>2</sup> = 13<sup>2</sup> + 91<sup>2</sup> As for second (common) case - that's even more complicated.

*Use-case*

That may be useful when dealing with some things, which supposed to be order-independent and need to be unique. For example, if we want to find cartesian product of many arrays and we want result to be unique independent of order, i.e. `<x,z,y>` is equal to `<x,y,z>`. It may be done with:

```
function decartProductPair($one, $two, $unique=false)
{
   $result = [];
   for($i=0; $i<count($one); $i++)
   {
      for($j=0; $j<count($two); $j++)
      {
         if($unique)
         {
            if($i!=$j)
            {
               $result[$i*$i+$j*$j]=array_merge((array)$one[$i],(array)$two[$j]);
               //           ^
               //           |
               //           +----//this is the place where F(i,j) is needed
            }
         }
         else
         {
            $result[]=array_merge((array)$one[$i], (array)$two[$j]);
         }
      }
   }
   return array_values($result);
}
```

Another use-case is to properly group sender and receiver in some SQL table, so that different senders/receivers will be differed while they should stay symmetric. Something like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS message_count,
  sender,
  receiver
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
-- this is the place where F(sender, receiver) is needed:
  sender*sender + receiver*receiver
```

(By posting samples I wanted to show that issue is certainly related to programming)

**The question**

As mentioned, the question is - what can be used as `F`? I want as simple `F` as it's possible. Keep in mind two cases:

- Integer `x>0`, `y>0`. `F(x,y) > 0`
- Any integer x, y and so any integer F(x,y) as a result

May be `F` isn't just an expression - but some algorithm to find desired result for any x,y (so tagging with [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) too). However, expression is better because it's more like that it will be able to use that expression in SQL or PHP or whatever. *Feel free to edit tagging because I'm not sure if two tags here is enough*

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/reversible-reflexive-function-with-unique-cardinality

Comment: Non efficient (possibly huge numbers) but correct solution is: define p_i= the ith prime number. F(i,j) = p_i*p_j

Comment: @Henrik I didn't get answer with `F(x,y) = {x,y}` (what is it?) - and interesting answer with left shift I've found non-applicable, because, obviously, integer overflow

Comment: What's wrong with a = max(x,y), b = obvious:  (a << 16) | b ? You'll have to limit the size of x and y anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `MAX_INTEGER` constant, and the result will need to hold `MAX_INTEGER**2` (say: be a `long`, if both are `int`'s). In that case, one such function is:

`f(x,y) = min(x,y)*MAX_INTEGER + max(x,y)`

*But* I propose a different solution: use a hash function (say md5) of the string resulting from the concatenation of str(min(x,y)), a separator (say ".") and str(max(x,y)). That is:

`f(x,y) = md5(str(min(x,y)) + "." + str(max(x,y)))`

It is not unique, but collisions are very rare, and probably OK for most use cases. If still worried about collisions, save the actualy {x,y} along with f(x,y), and check if collisions happened.

Comment: How can I hold something larger than maxint? Remember, this isn't just theoretical question - I need to store my result as integer value. I don't want to use `md5` since result should be integer value

Comment: Not sure what language you are using, but: (1) use `int` for `x` and `y`, and use `long` for the result. Or (2) if you know in advance some kind of a threshold on your `x` and `y` values. Otherwise, use the hash. Or finally: use a `bigint` class that has arbitrary precision, and use `int` for `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 4):

Most simple solution: `f(x,y) = x^5 + y^5`
No positive integer is known which can be written as the sum of two fifth powers in more than one way.
As for now, this is [unsolved math problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number).

Comment: This is good too. While in theory taxicab isn't unique - this will fit because I'm sure integer is much lesser than 1E18

Comment: +1 because this is cool and I learned something new. I think the OP wants something that he can't have, and that a solution that fits in an `int` (or: the same data type as the inputs). This is of course impossible, and if we forego that requirement than a better (imho) solution is what I proposed. But still: LIKE.

Comment: @NitzanShaked actually, solution with left shift will fit better because I'll be able to work with 16-bit integers (so if I'll declare maxint as 65535 I'll get my function for whole longint) - while here it's more narrow set because of 5-power usage. However, both are upvoted

Comment: Very nice, but grows too quickly for any use at which OP hinted.

Answer (score 1):

Sort input numbers and interleave their bits:

```
x = 5
y = 3
Step 1. Sorting: 3, 5
Step 2. Mixing bits: 11, 101 -> 1_1_, 1_0_1 -> 11011 = 27
So, F(3, 5) = 27
```

Comment: Could you explain more about "interleave bits" ? Also interesting - what about negative values?

Comment: Doesn't interleaving the bits mean you'll need a larger type to hold the result? Basically all solutions are such, so left-shifts (or multiplication as I suggest) work as well. Much as @laune said in the comments to the question.

Comment: Negative numbers may be mapped to positive before calculating f(x,y): `mapping(x) = abs(x)*2+sign(x)`, where sign(x) is 0 or 1.

Comment: @Nitzan Shaked ++ It should be pretty obvious that the cardinality of the result domain is N*N/2 where N is the domain for F's operands.

Comment: F(0,27) = 101000101 = 325

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  You can simply concatenate the binaries... No diff, you must set a limit for F's operands...

Comment: @laune of course. That is why we either have to have a larger result type (or settle for collisions, as I proposed).

Comment: @laune - My method does not require numbers to be limited.  It works for arbitrary long natural numbers.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, with F being of the type "integers of unlimited precision", too. But I don't think that was OP's original idea. Your algorithm would the advantage that you don't have to  know the domains for x and y beforehand and still produce a unique result. But if you (see OP's use case) need to have and array for the result...

Answer (score 1):

A compact representation is x*(x+3)/2 + y*(x+1) + (y*(y-1))/2, which comes from an arrangement like this:

```
    x->
y   0    1    3    6   10   15 
|   2    4    7   11   16
v   5    8   12   17
    9   13   18
   14   19   
   20
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Stackoverflow:mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way][1], if we symmetrize the formula we would have the following:

```
(x + y) * (x + y + 1) / 2 + min(x, y)
```

This might just work. For

```
(x + y) * (x + y + 1) / 2 + x
```

is unique, then the first formula is also unique.
[1]: [Mapping two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way)