# Generating Unique ID Number from Two Integers

Tags: numbers, integer, unique

Given 2 integers a and b (positive or negative). Is there any formula / method for generating unique ID number?

note: 1. result from f(a,b) and f(b,a) should be different. 2. calculating f(a,b) for x times (x > 1), the result should be same.

To make clear about the question, this function f(n) = (n * p) % q (where n=input sequence value, p=step size, q=maximum result size, n=non-negative integer, n < q, p < q, p ⊥ q (coprime)) will give unique ID number.

But, in my requirement, input are two numbers, a and b can be negative or positive integer.

any reference is appreciable

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you mean generating a unique id? You can create an auto incremented id generation but if you create random numbers with a and b you have to check if that value exists, otherwise it is not unique. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: is there a known maximum upper and lower limit of these integers?

Comment: @Spacedman: thanks Spacedman for fast response, there is no limit for this integers..

Comment: In practice -- when working with computers -- there's always an upper limit.

Comment: And the output "number" has to be an integer too? No decimals?

Comment: If the numbers really are unbounded then this is a number theory question and should prob be on the maths stackexchange site. And then I think the answer is "cant be done" (because you are mapping a 2d space to a 1d space).

Comment: @davidhigh : yup.. I know that.. but what I mean var a and b in this case is not really big.. maybe -1000 until 1000

--Spacedman : yes, I wish it would be better if the result is integer, but it's ok if not integer.. maybe I can get something for the idea

Comment: @Spacedman: my bad.. I dunno if there is exist math stackoverflow.. ok.. I will try to move this question

Comment: have you considered my answer, yet? It's one possibility to do what you request -- but in fact, you could use any isomorphism from Z x Z -> Z (here Z means the set of integer numbers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way)

Answer (score 4):

You could generate a long (64 bit) from 2 integers (32 bit) by just right bit shifting the first integer with 32 and then add the second integer.

```
private long uniqueId(int left, int right) {
    long uniqueId = (long) left;
    uniqueId = uniqueId <<< 32;
    uniqueId += (long) right;
    return uniqueId;
}
```

Comment: sorry for long time to reply Stefaan, I appreciate your idea.. thanks and sorry

Answer (score 1):

Say your integers have a range in `[MIN_INT,MAX_INT]`. Then, given an integer `n` from this range, the function

```
f(n) = n - MIN_INT
```

attributes a unique positive integer `f(n)` in the range `[0, MAX_INT - MIN_INT]`, which is often called a *rank*.

Denote `M = MAX_INT - MIN_INT + 1`. Then, to find a unique id `g(n,m)` of two concatenated integers `n` and `m`, you can use the common access style also used for two-dimensional arrays:

```
g(n,m) = f(n)*M + f(m)
```

That is, you simply offset the second integer by the largest possible value and count on.

Practically, of course, you have to be careful in order to avoid overflows -- that is, you should use some suited data types.

---

Here is an example: say your integers come from the range `[-1,4]`, thus `M=6`. Then, for two integers `n=3` and `m=-1` out of this range, `g(n,m) = 3*6 + 0 = 18` can be used as id.

Comment: sorry for long time to reply, I appreciate your idea.. thanks davidhigh :)