# Can I use Elegant Pairing Function as primary key in DB?

Tags: database, algorithm, math, primary-key, primary-key-design

I'm writing a server that allows multiple users can modify a post.
So I created Permission table that contains user id, post id, and permission data.
And I just wanted to query this with only one value (I just thought that querying with one value is more efficient than querying with two values), so I googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612).
However, I also found that [Cantor Pairing Function isn't unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2437979),
so we can't use Cantor Pairing Function as a primary key.

But that only deals with Cantor way, not [Elegant Pairing Function (by Matthew Szudzik)](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf)
How about Elegant pairing function?
Is it safe to use Elegant pairing key as primary key in database?
Or should I just give up and query that with two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless single ID field constraint is enforced by your storage, I believe that this is an example of famous

> *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.* (D.Knuth).

Note that Cantor pairing function is not unique for ***real*** numbers but it is unique for ***integers*** and I don't think that your IDs are non-integer numbers. I think this is quite the same for the Elegant Pairing Function you reference because structurally it is based on the same idea. If you need a specific counter-example, here is one:

```
ElegantPair(1, 2) = 2^2 + 1 = 5 = 2.1^2 + 0.59 = ElegantPair(0.59, 2.1)
```

On the other hand the real problem is that you can't fit two 32-bit (or whatever size you use) int values into a single int value of the same size no matter what clever trick you use. The trick behind pairing functions is based on the fact that whole **N** is infinite and **N**x**N** has the same "size" as just **N** which is obviously not true for a fixed-size real (computer) world integers. Thus whatever mapping you use over fixed-sized ints, it will not be unique.