# Calculating a nested root in C

Tags: c, recursion, sqrt

I was asked to calculate the following nested root expression using **recursion** only.

[image]

I wrote the code below that works, but they allowed us to **use only one function** and 1 input `n` for the purpose and not 2 like I used.
Can someone help me transform this code into one function that will calculate the expression? cant use any library except functions from `<math.h>`.

output for n=10: `1.757932`

```
double rec_sqrt_series(int n, int m) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (m > n)
        return 0;
    return sqrt(m + rec_sqrt_series(n, m + 1));
}

double helper(int n) {
    return rec_sqrt_series(n, 1);
}
```

Comment: **Can someone help me transform this code into one function that will calculate the expression?** what? Help you get rid of the `helper`?

Comment: If the arguments are wrong, i would call `abort()` (from `<stdlib.h>`), not silently return 0.

Comment: @4386427 yes exactly, get rid of the helper and only use 1 input n, instead of using n and m.

Comment: @Kaz can't use any library except of <math.h>. so if you have a solution with that it will be great

Comment: Your teacher probably means not using any mathematics related library that might supply part of the solution somehow.  Surely you can use `<stdio.h>` and `printf` to test your code, right?

Comment: @Kaz yes, i can use only <stdio.h>, <math.h>, printf.

Comment: @pastaleg Thanks for the heads up - did not notice recursion requirement.

Comment: no problem @chux-ReinstateMonica, sitting here myself trying to figure out if it is viable

Comment: @pastaleg confident it is - just twisted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: what do you think of my *twisted* solutions?

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Twisied.  @pastaleg How about useless recursion? `double nested_root(unsigned n) {
  double x = 0.0;
  if (n > 0) {
    x = nested_root(0);
    for (unsigned i = n; i > 0; i--) {
      x = sqrt(i + x);
    }
  }
  return x;
}`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yes, a simpler abuse of the rules.

Comment: My guess is this is not really about the code, but about identifying a non-recursive definition for the series.

Comment: @Oppen: If the goal of the assignment were to fund a non-recursive expression of the function, it probably would not request that the problem be solved using “recursion only.” Certainly a simple loop would calculate the result easily. Although I am generally suspicious when these questions are posted to Stack Overflow without the actual text of the assignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right. And you're right in being suspicious, too.

Answer (score 7):

Use the upper bits of `n` as a counter:

```
double rec_sqrt_series(int n)
{
    static const int R = 0x10000;
    return n/R < n%R ? sqrt(n/R+1 + rec_sqrt_series(n+R)) : 0;
}
```

Naturally, that malfunctions when the initial `n` is `R` or greater. Here is a more complicated version that works for any positive value of `n`. It works:

- When `n` is negative, it works like the above version, using the upper bits to count.
- When `n` is positive, if it is less than `R`, it calls itself with `-n` to evaluate the function as above. Otherwise, it calls itself with `R-1` negated. This evaluates the function as if it were called with `R-1`. This produces the correct result because the series stops changing in the floating-point format after just a few dozen iterations—the square roots of the deeper numbers get so diluted they have no effect. So the function has the same value for all `n` over a small threshold.

```
double rec_sqrt_series(int n)
{
    static const int R = 0x100;
    return
        0 < n ? n < R ? rec_sqrt_series(-n) : rec_sqrt_series(1-R)
              : n/R > n%R ? sqrt(-n/R+1 + rec_sqrt_series(n-R)) : 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but assumes 32-bit ints :)

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes: Nah, that is why `R` is separate, so it can be tuned. Before `n` reaches 32, the return value stops changing for IEEE-754 binary64, and before it reaches 256, the return value stops changing for reasonable formats for `double`. So I am considering an alternate version that transforms clamps inputs above `R`, but it needs to use the sign bit, and I am still working on it.

Comment: There are [other pairing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919612/) you can use, but none as simple as yours. Their main advantage is typically that they work with arbitrary precision, but OP never mentioned that as a requirement.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes: Done. Now produces the correct answer for any positive `n` regardless of the width of `int`.

Answer (score 5):

This problem begs for contorted solutions.

Here is one that uses a single function taking one or two `int` arguments:

- if the first argument is positive, it computes the expression for that value
- if the first argument is negative, it must be followed by a second argument and performs a single step in the computation, recursing for the previous step.
- it uses `<stdarg.h>` which might or might not be allowed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double rec_sqrt_series(int n, ...) {
    if (n < 0) {
        va_arg ap;
        va_start(ap, n);
        int m = va_arg(ap, int);
        va_end(ap);
        if (m > -n) {
            return 0.0;
        } else {
            return sqrt(m + rec_sqrt_series(n, m + 1));
        }
    } else {
        return rec_sqrt_series(-n, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is another solution with a single function, using only `<math.h>`, but abusing the rules in a different way: using a macro.

```c
#include <math.h>

#define rec_sqrt_series(n)  (rec_sqrt_series)(n, 1)
double (rec_sqrt_series)(int n, int m) {
    if (m > n) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        return sqrt(m + (rec_sqrt_series)(n, m + 1));
    }
}
```

Yet another one, **strictly speaking recursive**, but with single recursion level and no other tricks. As [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) commented, it uses a `for` loop which might be invalid under the OP's constraints:

```
double rec_sqrt_series(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return rec_sqrt_series(-n);
    } else {
        double x = 0.0;
        for (int i = -n; i > 0; i--) {
            x = sqrt(i + x);
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that works i guess. thank you very much for all the help

Comment: Last `double rec_sqrt_series(int n)`, IMO, meets OP's goals by using the sign as a recursion flag.  (I'd drop the `else` as not needed as `return` is in `if`.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: dropping the `else` is possible of course but I kinda like to symmetry of both branches of the `if` returning a result, sort of functional programming style.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I expect the assignment’s requirement of “recursion only” precludes iteration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yes, I thought the same, but did not get feedback from the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Without mathematically transforming the formula (I don't know if it is possible), you can't truly use just one parameter, as for each element you need two informations: the current step and the original `n`. However you can *cheat*. One way is to encode the two numbers in the `int` parameter (as shown by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61033645/2805305)).

Another way is to store the original `n` in a static local variable. At the first call we save `n` in this static variable, we start the recursion and at the last step we reset it to the sentinel value:

```
// fn(i) = sqrt(n + 1 - i + fn(i - 1))
// fn(1) = sqrt(n)
//
// note: has global state
double f(int i)
{
    static const int sentinel = -1;
    static int n = sentinel;

    // outside call
    if (n == sentinel)
    {
        n = i;
        return f(n);
    }

    // last step
    if (i == 1)
    {
        double r = sqrt(n);
        n = sentinel;
        return r;
    }

    return sqrt(n + 1 - i + f(i - 1));
}
```

---

Apparently `static int n = sentinel` is not standard C because `sentinel` is not a compile time constant in C (it is weird because both gcc and clang don't complain, even with `-pedantic`)

You can do this instead:

```
enum Special { Sentinel = -1 };
static int n = Sentinel;
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I'm afraid the initializer `static int n = sentinel;` is not fully conformant in C because `sentinel` is not a constant expression as per the C Standard. It works in C++, and it compiles with current versions of gcc and clang in C mode but not MSVC 2017, but you should probably write `static int n = -1;` see https://godbolt.org/z/8pEMnz

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes ish. Thank you for pointing this out. Interesting compiler behavior. I've asked about this in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61037093/2805305

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

It relies on `int` being 32 bits. The idea is to use the upper 32 bit of a 64 bit `int` to

1) See if the call was a recursive call (or a call from the "outside")

2) Save the target value in the upper 32 bits during recursion

```
// Calling convention:
// when calling this function 'n' must be a positive 32 bit integer value
// If 'n' is zero or less than zero the function have undefined behavior
double rec_sqrt_series(uint64_t n)
{
  if ((n >> 32) == 0)
  {
    // Not called by a recursive call
    // so start the recursion
    return rec_sqrt_series((n << 32) + 1);
  }

  // Called by a recursive call

  uint64_t rn = n & 0xffffffffU;

  if (rn == (n >> 32)) return sqrt(rn);      // Done - target reached

  return sqrt (rn + rec_sqrt_series(n+1));   // Do the recursive call
}
```