# Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'unordered_set< vector<int> >'

Tags: c++, hash, set, unordered-set

It seems like when I try to define an unordered_set of vector, I get an error saying: "Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of `unordered_set< vector<int> >` ." This doesn't happen when I define a regular (ordered) set: `set< vector<int> >`. It seems like I need to define `hash<vector<int>>` in order to get rid of the error.

Does anyone know why I get this error only when I use `unordered_set`? Shouldn't both data structures use hashing, so why would an unordered_set need a custom-defined hash function? In fact, shouldn't a regular (ordered) `set` need some custom-defined comparator as well in order to order the `vector<int>` data structures?

Comment: `std::vector` already has an overloaded `operator <`.  That's why it works with `std::set`.

Comment: `std::set` doesn't use hashing.

Comment: Suggest use `unordered_set<T*>` instead of `unordered_set<T>`, which is used by mysql-server and rocksdb heavily

Answer (score 18):

It's because unordered_set is using std::hash template to compute hash for its entries and there is no std::hash for pairs. You have to define custom hash to use unordered_set.

```
    struct vector_hash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator () (std::pair<T1, T2> const &v) const
    {
        return std::hash<T1>()(v.size());    
    }
};
```

and then declare your unordered_set as -

```
std::unordered_set< vector<int>, vector_hash> set;
```

This hash function is not good. It's just an example.

Comment: Why does an `unordered_set` of `vector<int>` need a hash function for `pair`? Wouldn't it need a hash function for `vector<int>`?

Comment: If you are looking for a good hash function for a pair<int,int> https://stackoverflow.com/a/682617/10630458

Comment: I'm not seeing that there is such a member function std::pair::size(). How does this compile? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

Answer (score 7):

> Shouldn't both data structures use hashing

No. This is documented, you can always look it up yourself:

- [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

  > `std::set` is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type `Key`. Sorting is done using the key comparison function `Compare`. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees

  Note that `Compare` defaults to [`std::less<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) overloads `operator<`.
- [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), for comparison

  > Unordered set is an associative container that contains a set of unique objects of type Key. Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity.

  > Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its value

  and the Hash type parameter defaults to [`std::hash<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). This has a list of specializations for standard library types, and `std::vector` is not included on that list.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no general specialization of `std::hash` for `std::vector`. There is only a specialization for `std::vector<bool>`, which is not very helpful:

```
int main()
{
    std::hash<std::vector<bool>> hash_bool;  // ok
    std::hash<std::vector<int>> hash_int;  // error
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PjE9bv).

The reason IMHO is that there is no standard way to combine hashes. Because you have to combine hashes for all elements in order to construct the hash for the whole vector. But why there is no standard way to combine hashes - this is the mystery.

You can use [`boost::hash`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/hash/tutorial.html) or [`absl::Hash`](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/hash) instead, e.g.:

```
unordered_set<vector<int>, boost::hash<vector<int>>>
```

Be aware that the hash codes computed by `absl::Hash` are not guaranteed to be stable across different runs of your program. Which might be either a benefit (if you aim for security), or a disadvantage (if you aim for reproducibility).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not related to `std::vector` issue directly, but in my case I've got the "Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor" error on `std::string`, just because I did not include the `<string>` header file.

I mean that that error can happen when `unordered_map` is used on forward declared type:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string_view>
//#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto m = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>{};
}
```

Answer (score -7):

set use self balancing trees whereas unordered_set uses pure hashing.